# Sequence of loading of provider in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

In what sequence the following provider are loaded in AngularJs:

Config, run , service, factory, provider, constant, values, controller,
directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to read the **[`documentation`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/guide/module)** recommended.

Here's the calling order:

**app.config()**

**app.run()**

**directive's compile functions**

**controllers**

**providers**